# transformation of functions.

Tags: functions, transformation

Let $f: A \rightarrow K, f(x)=\sqrt{2 x+c}-1,$ where $A$ is the maximal domain of $f$ and $c$ is a real number.

i. For what value(s) of $c$ does $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ have no real roots?

ii. For what value(s) of $c$ does $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$  have exactly one real solution?

My answers:
i)
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{2 x+c}-1=x\\
&2 x+c=(x+1)^{2}\\
&x^{2}+2 x+1=2 x+c\\
&\begin{array}{rl} 
& x^{2}+1-c=0 \\
a=1 & b=0 \quad c=(1-c)
\end{array}
\end{aligned}

.
.

\begin{array}{c}
D<0, b^{2}-4 a c<0 \\
0^{2}-4(1)(1-c)<0 \\
-4+4 c<0 \\
-1+c<0 \\
\therefore c<1
\end{array}

ii)

\begin{aligned}
&\begin{array}{l}
x^{2}+1-c=0 \\
b^{2}-4 a c=0 \\
0^{2}-4(1)(1-c)=0
\end{array}\\
&-4(1-c)=0\\
&\begin{array}{l}
1-c=0 \\
c=1
\end{array}
\end{aligned}

Answer is $c=1$ or $c>2$

How to do I know that $C>2$ without a calculator

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find $f^{-1}(x)$, whatever the value of $c$ is. First note that the range of $f$ is $[-1,\infty)$ (since $\sqrt{2x+c}$ may attain any nonnegative value).

Here's the easy way to find $f^{-1}(x)$: from $x$ to $f(x)$ we

- multiply $x$ by $2$;
- add $c$
- take the square root
- subtract one

The opposite process is

- add one
- square
- subtract c
- divide by $2$

So $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2-c}{2}$, defined for $x\geq -1$

So the equation "$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$" actually becomes
$$\sqrt{2x+c}-1=\frac{(x-1)^2-c}{2}$$
which is what you should try to solve.

Here's an equivalent way, which might be easier: Note that "$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$" is equivalent ot $x=f^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))$,
$$x=\frac{(\frac{(x-1)^2-c}{2}-1)^2-c}{2}$$

---

As a further alternative, which avoid computing $f^{-1}(x)$, you can note that "$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$" is equivalent to $f(f(x))=x$, which becomes
$$\sqrt{2(\left(\sqrt{2x+c}-1)+c\right)}-1=x$$

Comment: Hi the question is not to find the inverse ( of which i already know how to find). The question is asking for what values of x will be if the two graph have one real solution. I have worked one out and needing help for the other x value.